# How to make reCaptcha required while submitting form. (as formValidation) JQuery

Tags: jquery, required-field, recaptcha

I have putted three the scripts (generated while creating reCaptcha)

to show the reCaptcha on my wizard form and its working fine (for the specified url for which it is generated) but when i click the submit button i am unable to make it required to check it, form getting submit without clicking it. ?
how to do it in jQuery or whaterver (although i have helper play form with buttons coded in jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't verify that the puzzle was solved because Javascript is prohibited from making cross-domain XMLHttpRequests requests for security reasons.

What you need to do is make a call to your PHP (or some server side technology) script, and verify the captcha through that.

If you are using PHP, here is a [Google Developer Post](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php) that walks you through the steps of implementing reCaptcha. Focus on the section that explains how to verify that the user entered the right answer.